# Best way to post JavaScript data to Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to take a serialized list in JavaScript and save it to an instance variable array(or hash) in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript code runs on the client, and your Rails code runs on the server, so there's no way to *directly* pass your Javascript data to Rails. Instead you'd likely have to set up a controller to specifically handle an HTTP POST with your serialized data as the payload.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options on how to do this:

http://www.activars.com/2009/04/13/pass-javascript-variables-to-rails-controller/

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a hidden field with the list values and then setup a controller action to handle the data.